# Permanently highlight all occurrences of text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, highlighting

In [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/), when I select (eg. double-click) a "word", it gets highlighted. It needs to be separated with a non-alpha character from the rest of the text. The highlight remains until the text is selected.

Is there a way to make this highlight "permanent", ie. remain when the word is not selected any more?

Nice to have: can partial words be highlighted?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just use the **mark** feature.

1. Open the Search & Replace dialog and go to the **Mark** tab.
2. Enter your search term and click **Mark All**.

   [image]
3. All occurrences are now permanently marked:

   [image]

To remove the marks, simply open the dialog again and click **Clear all marks**.

Alternatively, while you have the word selected, you can use the **Mark** functionality in the **Search** menu:

[image]

This also allows you to *mark* all occurrences of a given string in the document (and you can even have multiple markers going on simultaneously).

Please note that both approaches work perfectly fine with partial words. In fact, multiple markers can apply to the same partial string. Here I've used a marker for `port` and one for `mporta`:

[image: Using multiple markers simultaneously]

Comment: Warning. This does not permanently highlight the text. After closing and re-opening the file the marks will be gone.

Answer (score 14):

### Simple Solution

- `Select` your text.
- Right-click on the text area.
- Choose `Style Token` from the context menu.
- `Apply` the style you need.
- Done.

Comment: This one is very handy!

Comment: This is also not permanent. All highlighting will be gone upon re-opening the file.

Comment: @Makesh I am not aware of any permanent solution which will work on re-opening the file.

Comment: It is gone after reload of the file also. This is a usual scenario for logfiles.

Comment: @Nicolas You can check my answer, where you define your own language. I use that for logs and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own language. This allows you to simply select that language for any file, without having to manually mark all words again. It will also work when the file is reloaded from the disk.

1. Go to `Language > User Defined Language > Define your language...`
2. In the `Keyword Lists` tab, add the words you want highlighted. You have 8 groups, each one can have a different style. Click `Styler` to set the style
3. You can specify the extension of the file, so all such files will always have that style when opened, in the `Ext.` textbox at the top
4. Once you're done, click `Save As...`
5. To select the language for a file, go to `Language`, and you should see you language almost at the bottom

I use that at least with log files, where `Trace`, `Debug`, `Info`, ... have all a different color.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, we are using this mechanism for basic formatting already. Maybe this is the right approach for the OP also. But in addition, when analysing log files, there are volatile values that help being highlighted. These are only relevant for the current scenario.