# How to keep highlighted text in notepad ++ even if I restart my computer?

Tags: notepad++, highlighting

I want to highlight text in my notepad++. I already use the mark option. But it is not permanent. Whenever I restart my notepad++, all the markings are gone. Is there any solution that my highlighted text will be there even if I restart my computer or restart notepad++ instance?

Comment: This post here should help you out. http://superuser.com/questions/567703/permanently-highlight-all-occurrences-of-text-in-notepad

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it doesn't cover my problem. They are all gone after restarting the notepad++ instance.

Comment: You are right I just tried it. Im going to look into this.

Answer (score 2):

According to this post as well as several others that I have read, this is not a feature and cannot be achieved as of now.

**Notepad++**

-Only allows you to mark the words for the time being.

-If notepad++ was to save the files with highlight format only Notepad++ would be able to use the files made. Unless the user deleted all highlighting before trying to use the file.

-Looks like this feature has been wanted for a while but no plug-ins have been made that I can find.

The Above answers your question on Highlighted text not staying after a restart. 
Because in Conclusion the Program is not made to save the Highlighted Text it is only a visual for the user when you are currently working on the file.

The Highlighting is also setup for use as Replacing highlighted areas with text as example is stated here [Notepad++ - Highlight text and insert html](https://superuser.com/questions/453235/notepad-highlight-text-and-insert-html-tag-tag-around-it) Hope this helps.

[Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) May offer some plug-ins that the User will have to configure.

There are several add-ons available one option would be this one would be this [How To Set Up Sublime Text for Markdown Editing](http://plaintext-productivity.net/2-04-how-to-set-up-sublime-text-for-markdown-editing.html)

Only issue with sublime is it costs and at the time is set at 70$ a license